# "Invalid Vault Token Specified." hashi_vault.vault_pki_generate_certificate - Ansible

Tags: ansible, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to generate certificates from Hashicorp's Vault with the help of Ansible as described in this link https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/collections/community/hashi_vault/vault_pki_generate_certificate_module.html

my Ansible task:

```yaml
- name: Login and use the resulting token
  community.hashi_vault.vault_login:
    # url: http://127.0.0.1:8100
    auth_method: token
    token_file: /tmp/vault_token
  register: login_data

- name: check token
  debug:
    msg: "{{ login_data }}"

- name: Generate a certificate with an existing token
  community.hashi_vault.vault_pki_generate_certificate:
    role_name: blinchik_user_cert_ica2
    common_name: local-docker-registry.service.brain.consul
    url: http://127.0.0.1:8100/v1/pki/brain/v1/ica2/v1/issue
    ttl: 5760h
    auth_method: token
    token: "{{ login_data.login.auth.client_token }}"
  register: cert_data
```

the login part seems to work, However, generating the certificates does not.

error

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Invalid Vault Token Specified."}
```

I did test the token generated in `"{{ login_data }}"` and it is a valid token.

With Consul-template, I can generate the certificates in this way:

```
{{ with secret "pki/brain/v1/ica2/v1/issue/blinchik_user_cert_ica2" "common_name=local-docker-registry.service.brain.consul" "ttl=30536000" }}
{{ .Data.certificate -}}
{{ end }}
```

any ideas what could be wrong in my configuration?

Comment: Please share the output of that debug task, showing the token, and confirm what hostname:port you are running on (your example uses two different Vault address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was trying to put my cert route in Vault in the wrong place (the VAULT_ADDR or `url` ). Instead I put it in the `engine_mount_point` and it worked.

the working configuration is:

```yaml
- name: Generate a certificate with an existing token
  community.hashi_vault.vault_pki_generate_certificate:
    role_name: blinchik_user_cert_ica2
    engine_mount_point: pki/brain/v1/ica2/v1
    common_name: local-docker-registry.service.brain.consul
    url: http://127.0.0.1:8100
    ttl: 5760h
    auth_method: token
    token: "{{ login_data.login.auth.client_token }}"
  register: cert_data
  no_log: true
```